# Copying values from one tensor to another tensor based on index mapping and averaging values mapped to same index

Tags: python, pytorch

I have one input tensor and an index mapping. I want to create output tensor based on that index mapping.

For example:
input = torch.tensor([12, 56, 45, 37], dtype=torch.float)

index_map = torch.tensor([-1, 1, 2, 1, 3, -1])
(-1 in index_map represents it is not mapped to anything)

grad = torch.tensor([4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7], dtype=torch.float)

I want to copy values from grad to input based on index_map. The values which are mapped to same index should be averaged. For e.g. grad[1] and grad[3] are both mapped to index 1, so final value at index 1 should be 1.5

Output tensor should be like :
tensor([12.,  1.5,  5.,  6.])

My code is:

```
input = torch.tensor([12, 56, 45, 37], dtype=torch.float)
input = torch.cat([input, torch.tensor([-1], dtype=torch.float)])
index_map = torch.tensor([-1, 1, 2, 1, 3, -1])
grad_out = torch.tensor([4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7], dtype=torch.float)
input[index_map] = grad_out
input = input[:4]
print(input)
```

Above code copies the latest value but does not average it out.